# How to add a button to the Qdockwidget Layers in Qgis 3 with PyQgis

Tags: layers, pyqgis-3, widget, context-menu

I want to add a plugin for styles to the layers panel. So I am trying to find a way to add a button to the toolbar of the layers-panel. Is this possible? If not is it possible to add a menu-item to the right-click menu of that same panel.

Comment: Have a look at [this plugin](https://github.com/YoannQDQ/layer-tree-icons)'s code, which adds a new option to the contextual menu.

Comment: Exactly where i was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Good. You can answer your own question for future visitors.